# How to find occurrences of char in an input string in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to write a function that will take a `String` and a `Char` and output the indexes where the char occurs in the string.

```
stringCount str ch = 
Input : "haskell is hard" `h`
Output:[0,11]
Input : "haskell is hard" `a`
Output:[1,12]
```

Please help me I'm struggling to understand Haskell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but since you mention you're a Haskell beginner, a list comprehension may be easiest to understand (I'm assuming this is homework, so you have to implement it yourself, not use `elemIndices`):

```
stringCount str ch = [ y | (x, y) <- zip str [0..], x == ch ]
stringCount "haskell is hard" 'a'
-- [1,12]
stringCount "haskell is hard" 'h'
-- [0,11]
```

Here we `zip`, the string `str` with the infinite list starting from 0, producing the tuples `('h', 0), ('a', 1), ('s', 2)`, etc. We then only select the tuples where the character (bound to `x`) equals the argument `ch` and return the index (bound to `y`) for each of them.

If you wanted to keep your current argument order but use `elementIndices` you can use the following:

```
stringCount' = flip elemIndices 
stringCount' "haskell is hard" 'h'
-- [0,11]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael Kohl and How can I do it with elemIndex ?

Comment: Sorry, it's `elemIndices`, not `elemIndex` (the latter only gives you the index of the first occurrence only). `elemIndices 'a' "haskell is hard"` gives you the desired result, so you'd just have to flip argument order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler but less sophisticated solution that the one post by karakfa:

```
stringCount :: String -> Char -> Integer -> [Integer]
stringCount [] c _ = []
stringCount (x:xs) c pos | x == c = pos:(stringCount xs c (pos+1))
                         | otherwise = stringCount xs c (pos+1)
```

The idea is that you go through the string char by char using recursion and then compare the actual caracter (head at the moment) with the char passed as argument. To keep track of the position I am using a counter called pos, and increment it for each recursion call.

Comment: Thanks a lot dreamcrash

Answer (score 0):

you can use `elemIndex` to walk through the list, or simply write your own

```
indexOf x = map fst . filter (\(_,s) -> s==x) . zip [0..]

indexOf 'a' "haskell is hard"
[1,12]
```

or with `findIndices`

```
import Data.List(findIndices)
findIndices (\x -> x=='a') "haskell is hard"
[1,12]
```