# How can I make a list of start-/end indices in Haskell?

Tags: string, list, haskell, substring, list-comprehension

I am trying to make a Haskell function that takes two strings as arguments, the first is the string we want to locate in the second argument, and return a list of tuples with the start- and end indices of every occurrence. For example,

```
indexTuples :: String -> String -> [(Int, Int)]
indexTuples "aa" "foobaarfoobaar" 

Output: [(4,5), (11,12)]
```

So far I have made a helping function that finds the indices ( I am trying to not use any extra methods other than Prelude methods, but implement by myself).

My helper function takes a string and a char and gives back the indices like so:

```
findPos :: (Num a1, Enum a1, Eq a2) => [a2] -> a2 -> [a1]
findPos str c = [index | (x, index) <- zip str [0..], x == c]
```

(I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434698/how-to-find-occurrences-of-char-in-an-input-string-in-haskell).) This function zips the string with the infinite list of numbers into tuples, and then selects the tuples where the character equals the argument `c` and returns the index for each of them. This gives me this output:

```
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> findPos "blablabla" 'b'
[0,3,6]
```

But how do I do this so that it takes in two strings instead?
Like this:

```
ghci> findPos "blablabla" "bl" 
[(0,1), (3,4), (6,7)]
```

I tried to just change the `c` from a char to a string object, but then I get several errors in `ghci`.

Comment: This looks pretty similar to this [recent Haskell question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69191633/11282404).

Comment: If you allow yourself to reuse existing functions from `Data.List`, you could write ```findPos haystack needle = findIndices (needle `isPrefixOf`) (tails haystack)```.

Comment: I cant use other functions than the ones in Prelude. But I can make my own functions, so I have been trying to make a findIndices, by following the same method as shown in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67012288/i-am-wanting-to-create-my-own-version-of-findindices-in-haskell, but I am not able to make it work on two strings, instead of a string and a list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (non-empty) string has a head element, a `Char`:

```
indexTuples :: String -> String -> [(Int, Int)]
indexTuples []     _   = []
indexTuples (c:cs) str =
```

Having found its index in the other string, -- a *list* of them for all the occurrences, -- using the function `findPos` which you already have,

```
  let
    ixs = findPos str c
```

we try each one of them

```
    len = length cs
    fits = [ (i,i+len) | i <- ixs, cs == (take len $ drop i str)]
```

and that's our answer.

```
   in
      fits
```

Comment: When I try to write this in VS Code, I get an error on ´cs == (drop 1 $ take len $ drop i str)´ , saying: 

Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely
    ‘(drop 1 $ take len $ drop i str)’
  In the expression: c == (drop 1 $ take len $ drop i str)
  In a stmt of a list comprehension:
    c == (drop 1 $ take len $ drop i str)typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)

 and when I try to fix it by moving the brackets to avoid using ´$´ I get another error. How can I rewrite this line without errors?

Comment: I don't see right now how that could be the case, maybe you made a typing error? but I'll test.

Comment: I am confused as well because I re-wrote it word for word.

Comment: You shouldn't write but copy-and-paste. I tried my code in GHCi, there's no error. the `drop 1` was erroneous, it shouldn't be there. but that passes as an off-by-one error. :)

Comment: @Mampenda From the error, it looks like you wrote `c == ...` instead of `cs == ...` when you transcribed the code. Whoops!

Comment: Yes, I did! Thank you.